# Как передать строку из activity в GET-запрос?

Tags: android, kotlin, activity, retrofit2

В `MainActivity` есть `EditText`, в который пользователь пишет nickname:

```xml
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/nicknameEditText"
    android:hint="Введите игровое имя"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Как полученный текст передать в GET-запрос?

```kotlin
interface ApiRequest {
    @GET("bridge?version=5&platform=PC&player=${R.id.nicknameEditText}")
    fun herList() : Call<TestHero>
}
```

Я попробовал кустарным путём как в коде выше, получил ошибку. В поиске есть только передача данных между двумя и более activity. Подскажите, как это реализовать правильно?

Comment: `@GET` это что? Retrofit, retrofit2 или что-то еще? [Укажите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1320007/edit) в тегах.

Comment: @это Retrrofit2 сейчас оформлю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В соответствии с [документацией Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/), параметр в GET-запрос можно передать следующим образом:

```kotlin
interface ApiRequest {
    @GET("bridge?version=5&platform=PC")
    fun herList(@Query("player") player: String) : Call<TestHero>
}
```

Далее, находясь в Активити, берем `EditText` по id:

```kotlin
val nicknameView = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.nicknameEditText)
```

Достаем его содержимое:

```kotlin
val nickname = nicknameView.text.toString()
```

Наконец, вызываем метод интерфейса api, передавая nickname в качестве player:

```kotlin
api.herList(nickname)
```

Comment: да но как с Activity передать через запрос ? я вот этого не понимаю немного, мне же надо где-то обьявить ```editTextTextMultiLine``` ? Или я чего-то не понимаю ?

Comment: добавил в ответ как вытащить данные из EditText

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо, хорошего дня